# How to overcome Error 429: Too Many Requests for Twitter API on Heroku server

Tags: python, heroku, twitter, urllib, tweets

I'm trying to run an application on Heroku, which does the following request:

```
curl 'https://api.twitter.com/2/timeline/conversation/{TWEET_ID_PARAMETER}.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweet=true&count=20&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel&include_quote_count=true' -H 'authorization: Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuH5E6I8xnZz4puTs%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA' -H 'x-guest-token: {X_GUEST_TOKEN_PARAMETER}'
```

To do that, I'm trying to get the x-guest-token with the following Python code:

```
def obtain_x_guest_token_for_twitter():
    data = parse.urlencode({}).encode()
    req = Request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/guest/activate.json', data=data)
    req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuH5E6I8xnZz4puTs%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA')
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Firefox')
    content = urlopen(req)
    x_guest_token = json.load(content)["guest_token"]
    return x_guest_token
```

Where `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuH5E6I8xnZz4puTs%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA` is the public Bearer token

I can make the script run on my local machine, but when I try to run it on my Heroku app it gives me a response of `HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests`

Can the heroku public IP be the problem? Maybe blacklisted?
If so, can I change the request to make it work? I have a registered Twitter application, I've tried with application authorization but doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That’s a private Twitter API endpoint, so there’s no support for you doing this from a Heroku server. The correct way to do this would be to use the [standard user timeline API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline). Use of private endpoints is not supported.

Comment: I’ve searched the docs but there is no support for what I want to do. My idea is to get the replies for a certain tweet